# Creating a javascript variable with a rails active record association

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I wan't to add an active record association to the dom, but am having trouble.

I have this editor class

```
 .editing
  .row
    .col-sm-3
    .col-sm-8
      .text-left
        #font-20
          .title-font
            .title-editor
```

As it is, the editor is empty which is what it's supposed to do.  But when someone edits their title, I wan't to be able to show their saved title.  The loading of this editor is with jquery and there is no page refreshing.

In my javascript I have access to the id of the object I want the title from

js:

```
var draft = $(e.target).attr('class');
var id = id.slice(draft);
```

With that id I want to add the objects title to the dom.
Something like this would be ideal, but I don't think it's possible.

```
var title = <%= Draft.find_by(id: $id).title %>
$('.title-editor').html(title);
```

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you will need to use ajax eventually...

First, you can make a slight change to your `drafts_controller.rb`. One of the ways to do this is the following:

```
def show # @draft is supposingly defined in a before_action callback
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json {
            render :json => {'title' = @draft.title}
        }
    end
end
```

So, if your `@draft` is : {id:1, title: 'hello'}, you will have:
`http://your.app.com/drafts/1.json` which will render `{"title":"hello"}`.

How do you use this? Easy... In your view, you bind this code to an event that will fire it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/drafts/"+id+".json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $('.title-editor').html(data.title);
    }
});
```